# Соеденить два текста в один

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

В этом куске кода нужно узнать, есть ли у сообщения какие то прикрепленные файлы, и если они есть, то добавить на них ссылку к основному тексту сообщения, а если прикрепленных файлов нет, то просто отправить текст.

```
async def on_message(message):
if message.channel.id == 624170997775335435:
    channel = c.get_channel(630044814297137203)
    msg = "[{1}] **{0.author}**: {0.content}".format(message, timestamp)
    if message.attachments:
        attachment = message.attachments[0].url
        msg + " + {0}".format(attachment)
        return msg
    await channel.send(msg)
```

Но в итоге он просто выводит мне сообщение, если прикрепленных файлов нет, а если они есть - он просто игнорирует сообщение.

Пример текста без прикрепленного файла:

```
[время] ник: текст
```

Пример текста с прикрепленным файлом:

```
[время] ник: текст + ссылка на прикрепленный файл
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 7 строке Вы не присваиваете результат переменной `msg`.

***Замените на:***

```py
msg += " + {0}".format(attachment)
#    ^
```

Также Вам следует удалить строку 8.

Comment: Я уже и так тоже пытался, но он все равно игнорирует сообщение если в нём есть какой нибудь прикрепленный файл. Сообщения с обычным текстом он воспринимает абсолютно нормально.

Comment: @lzrdblzzrd Попробуйте удалить строку `return msg` (оставив правку из моего ответа).

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!